# Using a for loop nested in a while loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

Bare with me, first post here and I have about 6 weeks of python knowledge.

Our assignment last week was to write a program that had a user input how many quizzes they've taken, the grade for that quiz, then print a summary of their average and grades for each quiz. Our professor is allowing us freedom in how exactly we write this. I wanted to try some things we have yet to cover. Got it worked out and all good to go, until this week. This week's assignment is to tweak last weeks code.

What he is asking for is to have an input that takes in the "title" of the quiz. There needs to be a review of the user's inputs. This is the example given.

[image: 1]

I know I could use a decremental for i in range type of thing, but I can't for the life of me figure out where and how to implement this. I seem to break the while loop if I place it in there. If I put I had 3 quizzes, and I enter those 3 in, it's not exiting the loop.

Here is what I have, apologize if it's messy. I spent some time googling how to best post on here so go easy on me :)

```py
name = input("Enter your first name: ")
Q = int(input("How many quizzes have you taken? "))
list1 = {}
minimum_quizzes = 2
passing_score = 70

if Q <= minimum_quizzes:
    print("You need at least three quiz scores to enter.")
    exit()
if Q >= minimum_quizzes:
    while True:
        print("Type 'exit' to exit.")
        quizTitle = input("Enter your quiz title:")
        if quizTitle.lower() == "exit":
            break
        quizGrades = input("Enter your quiz grade: \n")
        if quizGrades.lower() == "exit":
            break
        try:
            quizGrades = float(quizGrades)
            quizTitle = (quizTitle)
            list1.update({quizTitle :quizGrades})
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter only numbers for a grade")
        if len(list1) == Q:
            break

if len(list1) == Q:
    #list1.sort(reverse=True)
    print(f"Hello {name.capitalize()}, here is your entered quiz information: ")
    for k, v in list1.items():
        print(f"For quiz " + str(k) + " you received " + str(v),"%")

    if quizGrades >= passing_score:
        print(f"Your average quiz score is {sum(list1.values()) / len(list1)}%, which is above the minimum of {passing_score}%. Congrats, you've passed!")
    if quizGrades < passing_score:
        print(f"Sorry, your average quiz score is {sum(list1.values()) / len(list1)}%, you need an average of {passing_score}% to pass.")
```

If there is more information needed or an edit I should do on this post for formatting just let me know.
I appreciate any and all help, thanks!

Comment: it might be easier to get responses if you tagged the related programming language as well

Comment: will do, thank you, will remember to do that from here on out.